# Barrelshifter bitshifting and endianess

Tags: endianness, bit-shift, microblaze

I am correct in assuming that using the Microblaze barrelshifter to do a bitshift does not have endianness complications for simple shifting, eg

```
bslli r11, r11, 1
```

Would be the equivalent of `r11 == r11 * 2` regardless of the endianess selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endianness is only a concern when loading and storing words from and to byte-oriented memory. Once you have the value in a register, endianness is not an issue, and left-shifting will always move bits one step "upwards".